# How to move /data from internal storage to external SD card?

Tags: applications, root-access, internal-storage, external-sd, insufficient-memory

Apologies if this question was already asked.

Is it possible to move the `/data` directory to the external SD card?

I want all apps, app data, downloads and files to be automatically saved to the external SD card, instead of to the internal storage.

**Information:**

The internal storage is 178 MB, where 157 MB is used by apps. There's no internal SD card and my external SD card has 32 GB.

`/sdcard` is a symbolic link to `/storage/sdcard0` which is the 32 GB external SD card.

The device is rooted and uses CM11/4.4.2.

**Tried:**

1. Used `Link2SD` but could only move the APKs and dalvik. The app data and system apps couldn't be moved. Unfortunately I can't buy the new Link2SD.
2. Tried `FolderMount` but it doesn't allow access to `/`. It only allows access to the SD card.
3. Couldn't find fstab in `/etc` or `/system/etc`
4. Tried `Root External 2 Internal SD` but there's no internal SD card, just "internal storage" (shows 178 MB) and "SD card" (shows the 14 GB FAT32 partition on the external 32 GB SD card).

**Considered:**

```
su -
cp -r(p?) /data /storage/sdcard0/data
rm -r /data
ls -s /data /storage/sdcard0/data
```

However, I'm new to modifying Android and don't want to accidentally brick my device. When I tried to copy the data directory as root, it said that some files/directories did not exist.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Thank you for reading.

Edit: @programming Thanks for your help. I can't find the option on the storage page.

The storage page looks like:

```
Storage (clicking on `:` gives the option "USB computer connection")
Internal storage:
Total space ...
SD card:
Total space: ...
Erase SD card
```

There are no additonal options, as in: http://teckfront.com/use-external-sd-card-primary-storage-android-4-4-3-phone/

It's a Samsung smartphone with Android 4.4.2 and CM11 rom.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set your SD card as the default storage device, go to `settings > storage`, then select **default writing disk** to SD card. This will make your phone store everything to the SD card by default if possible. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello @programming, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the "default writing disk" option doesn't appear on Samsung, Android 4.4.2 with CM11. Should I upgrade to CM12/Android 5?

Comment: I got a new lg g4 and I can't find it either I don't know why it's not there.

Comment: Do you know another way to move /data from internal memory (no internal SD card) to an external SD card? I'd try symlinks, but could potentially corrupting /data lead to a brick?

Comment: Back it up before you try symlink

Answer (score 1):

Try AppMgrIII from the Play Store. It doesn't move everything to your MSD, but it moves quite a lot and it's easy and seamless.